# RabbitVCS icons question

Tags: nautilus, icons

In nautilus my folder shows up with a green tick icon, even though it contains files which are not committed (these show with a red exclamation mark). Is it correct that a folder should be marked as up to date even though it contains files which are not?  It makes it difficult for me to get an overview of which files I have changed because I have to check every single subfolder....?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that rabbitvcs isn't updating the folder status automatically. If you hit F5 it updates the current folder and changed subfolders get a red mark.